# Python: Running an action on every item in a folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to run movie.py's converter on every mp4 within a selected folder and I'm not sure how to make it work. Right now I'm using:

```
folpath=r'\\path'
files=list(glob.glob("{0}\*".format(folpath)))

transcribed_audio_file_name = "{0}speech.wav"
video_file_name = files

for filename in folpath:
   if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
     audioclip = AudioFileClip(video_file_name)
     audioclip.write_audiofile(transcribed_audio_file_name)
```

This runs without any given errors, but it also appears to be doing nothing. What is the correct way to refer to multiple files and link them back to the same action?

Comment: what is this supposed to do? seems like a list being assigned to a mis-named variable: `video_file_name = files`

Comment: @JacobIRR - The hope is it would go through the directory and then supply the mp4 files to be converted to wav with movie.py.  It works with a single file, but the hope is that I can get it to work with an updating list of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through the path to the directory instead of the files within it. Try this:

```
for filename in files:
   if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
     audioclip = AudioFileClip(video_file_name)
     audioclip.write_audiofile(transcribed_audio_file_name)
```

Comment: I found the big problem was that I was still using the video_file_name instead of just filename. It works as intended now. Thank you!